# Flexible Layout with CSS Rotated Text

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to layout a control that requires a text label to be rotated 270 degrees.  The width of the text label is variable, within reason (say, 100px to 500px).

[image]

I have tried to get this working in a jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/LhjNq/3/

but have run into a few problems I can't resolve:

1. Text in the non-rotated area (yellow and orange in the jsFiddle) is displaced to the right by the length of the text that is rotated.
2. The rotated text extends far below the bottom of the associated non-rotated area, overwriting other parts of the page.
3. In order to keep the label on the screen, I had to apply a *translate* transform with values hard-coded based on the length of the rotated text.

Is it possible to solve these problems using CSS transformations?

**UPDATE**

This jsFiddle makes problem 2. more apparent

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/LhjNq/47/

Comment: Removing the float on box_rotate seems to help a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem using SVG generated by a little jQuery wrapper called [mbFlipText](http://code.google.com/p/mbideasproject/wiki/mbFlipText) to manage IE support

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/cgtu5/7/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/LhjNq/53/

I think the only solution to correct the height of the divs is javascript.

To get rid of the extra space, I absolutely positioned the divs.

I don't think your rotation values for IE were quite right either, I changed them to 1.2 and it seemed to work. However still working on how to get IE to get the correct height for the divs, doesn't work same way.

EDIT:

IE actually changes the dimesions of the element, so you have to get the height. Also in IE, the rotated divs must be positioned from the top of the container, and not the bottom like the other browsers

EDIT: Updated Link

Comment: I get a 404 when I click on the jsFiddle link...?

Comment: Oops, not sure what happened there

Answer (score 0):

All transformation applied affected by `transform-origin`. By default it has value `50% 50%` which means all transformations will be made relatively to center of block.

The main idea is to change it to `0 0` (top left corner) — This will allow us to ommit ‘values hard-coded based on the length of the rotated text’
**[demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/3271876)**

Try to setup it:

[image]

**CSS:**

```
transform: rotate(-270deg);
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Comment: That code doesn't work in IE 8, so for all practical purposes, it may as well not work in any browser, unless Eric J. is targeting a very selected audience. Also it won't working older versions of Firefox, which are still relatively common, esp in places like schools.

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz For old ie you can achieve the same result with [**IETransformsTranslator**](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/). This code [will work in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) (ie9+, ff3.5+, chrome all, safari 3.1+, android 2.1+) I'm not showing prefixes for readability. You can use **prefixr** for correct and actual prefixes in your project.

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz why you are talking about property support with me if Eric J. decided to use it?

Comment: This code still shows the same problem that the Cyan colored text extends way below the yellow DIV, though it does fix the issue of the gap at the start of the text in the yellow div.

Comment: The IETransformsTranslater is very useful!  Was afraid I would have to do the math myself once I get the thing working in other browsers.

Comment: @EricJ. can you show visualization (image) of satisfied solution with this containers from jsfiddle? because I don't fully understand you

Comment: I added a new jsFiddle to the question that hopefully makes it more clear what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/LhjNq/47/